# How do I create an array of function pointers of different prototypes?

Tags: c++, function, oop, c++14

I have a few functions defined like this:

```
ParentClass*    fun1();
ParentClass*    fun2();
ParentClass*    fun3(bool inp=false);
ChildClass*     fun4();
ChildClass*     fun5(int a=1, int b=3);
```

I would like to put them into an array of some kind as follows:

```
void* (*arr[5])() = {
    (void* (*)())fun1,
    (void* (*)())fun2,
    (void* (*)())fun3,
    (void* (*)())fun4,
    (void* (*)())fun5
}
```

Now I would like to use this array of functions simply as

```
for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    someFunction(arr[i]());
```

Now I realize here that the issue is `void* (*arr[5])()`, but given that I only want to use the functions without supplying an argument, I would like all of these to be part of the same array.

These are very C-style ways to do it, though. Is there a better way to do it using Templates in C++?

Comment: Why do you want to discard the type from the return? does `ChildClass` not inherit `ParentClass`?

Comment: When I use it, I am actually casting it to `ParentClass`. I could make this a ParentClass* instead of void*, but that way I would have to type cast each entry into the array. I instead currently choose to cast it after I retrieve it from the array.

Comment: I miscommunicated through the question that I didn't want to use. I *do* want to use it. Modified the question accordingly.

Comment: In your first snippet you have declared `fun4` twice, is that a typo?

Comment: Yup. Corrected.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

C-style or not, what you have is straight undefined behaviour. Use lambdas:

```
void (*arr[5])() = {
    [] { fun1(); },
    [] { fun2(); },
    [] { fun3(); },
    [] { fun4(); },
    [] { fun5(); }
};
```

These are okay because they perform the call through the function's correct type, and are themselves convertible to `void (*)()`.

Forwarding the returned value stays simple enough, since the lambda provides a context for the conversion. In your case, since `ChildClass` supposedly inherits from `ParentClass`, an implicit conversion is enough:

```
ParentClass *(*arr[5])() = {
    []() -> ParentClass * { return fun1(); },
    []() -> ParentClass * { return fun2(); },
    []() -> ParentClass * { return fun3(); },
    []() -> ParentClass * { return fun4(); },
    []() -> ParentClass * { return fun5(); }
};
```

Comment: Does this make the return type of the functions `void`?

Comment: @vc669 Yes, since you don't use it anyway. However, you can also use the lambdas to reconcile the return types, which since I guess `ChildClass` inherits from `ParentClass` is just `[]() -> ParentClasss * { return fun1(); }`.

Comment: Did not realize that my usage(or lack thereof) would make a difference. I actually *do* intend to use it. I have updated the question accordingly and following your comment does the trick.

Comment: @Aconcagua yes, but consistency. One could avoid repetition by using a function that takes in all of the `fun*`'s at once and returns the array of wrapped functions as well.

Comment: Out of curiosity - would a decent compiler optimise the intermediate function call (lambda) away, if not needed, and actually place fun1 into the array?

Comment: @Aconcagua [Almost](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/qmJ_E-): it gets compiled into a single `jmp`. Although the function's body will be inlined into the lambda if applicable.

Answer (score 16):

> but given that I only want to use the functions without supplying an argument

It simply doesn't work like that. Did you ever wonder, then when you're putting function declarations in a header, why you have to write default parameters into the header and cannot place it in the definition in the implementation source file?

That's because the default parameters are in fact not "embedded" into the function, but used by the compiler to augment a function call with those parameters at a calling location, where those parameters are omitted. *(EDIT: Also, as @Aconcagua so keenly observed in a comment, since default parameters are usually defined as part of a header function declaration, any change of the default values requires a full recompilation of any compilation unit that included those headers, ergo function declarations, for the change to actually take effect!)*

While it's perfectly possible to do some really weird type casting madness to construct an array of function pointers like that, eventually you'll have to cast back to the original function call signature in order to not invoke undefined behavior.

If anything you'll have to bind the function pointer, together with a set of default parameters in some type that abstracts away the calling, does supply the parameters, and to the outside offers a polymorphic interface. So you'd have a `std::vector<function_binder>` or `function_binder[]` where function binder has an `operator()` that calls the function.

But when you're doing binding in the first place, you can bind it in an anonymous function, i.e. lambdas. At the time of lambda instantiation the default parameters are bound.

```
std::vector<void(*)()> fvec = {
    []{ func0(); },
    []{ func1(); },
    []{ func2(); }
};
```

Comment: Might be worth to mention that, as parameters are provided in header, if changing these, any translation units relying on need to be re-compiled to make these changes effective there as well...

Answer (score 10):

You can use [`std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind)

```
std::function<ParentClass *(void)> arr[5] = {
    std::bind(&fun1),
    std::bind(&fun2),
    std::bind(&fun3, false),
    std::bind(&fun4),
    std::bind(&fun5, 1, 3)
};
```

now you can do

```
for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    arr[i]();
```

You have to make sure every function parameter of all functions are bound.

This also works well with member functions. You just have to bind the object reference (e.g. `this`) as first parameter.

Comment: since C++11 and above there is no point to use `bind` since lambda is more handy and faster.

Comment: @Marek R - Depending on implementation `std::bind` might just return an lambda because it's return type is unspecified. It's probably just a matter of taste which one you use.

Comment: My taste says `std::bind` since if forces less disciplined developer to write small functions. Lambda is often overused and grows to ridicules sizes, but still it is easier to use and it is faster. `std::bind` creates complex templates which is annoying when analyzing a crash logs.

Comment: @Quentin - Thanks. Of course you can't have an array of `auto`. I corrected that.

Comment: @Detonar and now it's because `std::function` is way overkill for the job :p

Comment: @Quentin - Again a matter of Taste. `std::function` is the OO Aproach. I usually prefer `std::function` just because it's type safe.

Comment: I don't see what's specially OO in `std::function`, and it's not type-safe any more either -- one could argue it's *less* so, since its constructor can do some conversion magic with the parameters and return type as well.

Comment: Although this is a good answer, I feel that it's a little safer to use an array of lambdas, because that keeps the default arguments automatically consistent with the declarations used, rather than having to manually ensure they agree.  +1 anyway, though.

Answer (score 4):

A [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) solution:

```
#define RETURNS(...) \
  noexcept(noexcept(__VA_ARGS__)) \
  -> decltype(__VA_ARGS__) \
  { return __VA_ARGS__; }


template<auto f, class R, class...Args>
struct explicit_function_caster {
  using Sig=R(Args...);
  using pSig=Sig*;
  constexpr operator pSig()const {
    return [](Args...args)->R {
      return static_cast<R>(f(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
    };
  }
};

template<auto f>
struct overload_storer_t {
  template<class R, class...Args>
  constexpr (*operator R() const)(Args...) const {
    return explicit_function_caster<f, R, Args...>{};
  }
  template<class...Args>
  auto operator()(Args&&...args)
  RETURNS( f( std::forward<Args>(args)... ) )
};
template<auto f>
overload_storer_t<f> generate_overloads={};

#define OVERLOADS_OF(...) \
  generate_overloads< \
    [](auto&&...args) \
    RETURNS( __VA_ARGS__( decltype(args)(args)... ) ) \
  >
```

which is a lot of boilerplate, but gets us:

```
ParentClass* (*arr[5])() = {
  OVERLOADS_OF(fun1),
  OVERLOADS_OF(fun2),
  OVERLOADS_OF(fun3),
  OVERLOADS_OF(fun4),
  OVERLOADS_OF(fun5)
};
void (*arr2[5])() = {
  OVERLOADS_OF(fun1),
  OVERLOADS_OF(fun2),
  OVERLOADS_OF(fun3),
  OVERLOADS_OF(fun4),
  OVERLOADS_OF(fun5)
};
```

basically `generate_overloads<x>` takes a `constexpr` callable object `x` and lets you cast it at compile time to a pointer to a function of any compatible signature and call it with (almost) any signature.

Meanwhile, `OVERLOADS_OF` converts a function name into a `constexpr` object that does overload resolution on that function name.  I use it here because `fun3` as a function pointer does not know about its default arguments, but at overload resolution time it does.

In this particular case, it is far easier to just write toy lambdas to do this work; this is just an attempt to automate writing those toy lambdas for arbitrary compatible signatures.

Comment: `constexpr (*operator R() const)(Args...) const` oh what the hell... Also, is `decltype(args)(args)...` a replacement for `std::forward` or is there additional subtlety?

Comment: @Quentin Yes. I don't have the type of `args`.  The cast operator was there because the C++2a compilers didn't like `auto` based partial specialization, so I couldn't easily unpack a `Sig`: that is a type-deduced conversion operator to function pointer.

Comment: @Quentin Laugh, I think I converted to a const function pointer in a const method.  Accidentally: the fact the function pointer is const is pointless.

Answer (score 3):

Since you have tagged question with C++14 you should not use function pointers!

With C++14 you should prefer `std::function` and lambdas.

Also you should not use C style array, but only `std::array` and/or `std::vector`.

Also avoid raw pointers, use `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr`.

So simplest and best way to solve it is:

```
std::array<std::function<ParentClass*()>,5> arr {
    []() { return fun1(); },
    []() { return fun2(); },
    []() { return fun3(true); },
    []() { return fun4(); },
    []() { return fun5(7, 9); }
};
```

Why not simple array of pointers like in @Quentin answer? He used lambdas, but he can't use lambda which binds anything (if you need to).

Comment: Downvoted because `std::function` is a heavyweight facility, and the problem at hand does not require any of the functionality it provides over plain function pointers.